# I am trying to use flutter row widget with separate MainAxisValues for each child but its not working

Tags: dart, flutter

```
    Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.values [MainAxisAlignment.start, MainAxisAlignment.start, MainAxisAlignment.end],
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)) ,
                  color: Colors.teal,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/fly.jpg'),
                    // ...
                  ),
                  // ...
                )
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('James Henry', textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('status: '),
                  Text('Test Completed')
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: You can only supply a single value of `mainAxisAlignment`. See [this tutorial](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/layout).

Comment: i know that but i want two items to float left while the last one floats right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh just figured it out, i used an Expanded() widget on the item in the middle so that it will take all the remaining space, that way i get the other items to float to the extreme left and right.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is not valid. This is a quick and dirty way, but it gets the job done.:

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 40,
          height: 40,
          child: DecoratedBox(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)),
            color: Colors.teal,
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/fly.jpg'),
              // ...
            ),
            // ...
          )),
        ),
        Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'James Henry',
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[Text('status: '), Text('Test Completed')],
              )
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(),
          ),
        Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: i just tried that it didnt work, am not sure align works inside row